# spark - how to know which executor failed during Job execution and avoid them?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

background:

I'm running a spark job on a huge cluster with heavy workloads that constantly has ill-state nodes, which receives task, respond driver's heartbeat, not actually working, and takes forever to run, and may fail finally so driver need to re-submit the task somewhere else.

what I did to deal with the ill-state nodes:

I'm setting `spark.blacklist.enabled` to `True` to make sure the re-submitted task goes somewhere else (and in blink of an eye job finished). However, as I found out in log, the blacklist is only working for one stage:

```
Blacklisting executor 28 for stage 0
```

so next stage there will certainly try the ill node again, and there's high chance that the ill node may not come back to normal. I just met such situation that a node keeps failing task for 48 hours 180 times and just kill itself finally.

```
18/11/11 19:47:26 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1534870268016_1640615_01_000051 on host: ill-datanode. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node
```

executor like this drags spark application's performance heavily.

so I comes up with plan B: I kill it myself

I found there are 2 function to manage the executor called `SparkSession.sparkContext.killExecutor(executorId: String)` and `requestExecutors(numAdditionalExecutors: Int)`. But to remove executor using such function I must know which executor failed during last job.

How to do that?

Comment: There is a spark [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html), which can tell you if the executor failed or succeeded. You can search the submitted application by its name and then can get all details about executors and jobs.